# VBA Is searching through cells faster with Find method or going through every cell?

Tags: vba, excel, loops, find

I've created a VBA macro in Excel that looks for all the instances of specific function in all the worksheets. I've been able to successfully create it, but I'm trying to see what is the best method performance wise give the function I'm searching for could potentially used a large amount of times with a large workbook.

I've used two methods.

Method 1 - Loop through each individual cell and using the "instr" function to see if the cell formula contains thee function.

Method 2 - Use the Find and FindNext methods along with a do loop to only loop through the cells that actually have a function.

I was surprised to find when there are a large number of functions Method 1 is a lot faster (when there are very little method 2 works faster).

Can anyone explain how that could be?

Here's a sample with an example of my code.

On "Sheet1" I've placed a user defined function named "MyFunction" in cells A1:J5000.  Then in cells A5001:J10000 I've left them blank, but have colored them yellow to force the used range to be A1:J10000.

Even though Method 1 is looping through every 100,000 cells it is a lot faster than method 2 which only loops through the 50,000 cells found

Method 1 average run is about 171 ms and Method 2 average run is about 1,531 ms.

Example of my code for Method 1 and Method 2:

**Method 1**

```
Private Sub TestMethod1()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim MySheet As Worksheet, MyRange As Range, MyCell As Range
    Dim MyCellAddress As String, MyCellFormula As String, MyFunction As String
    Dim CountTotalCells As Long, CountTotalFunctions As Long

    Dim sw, swEndTime As Long
    Set sw = New StopWatch
    sw.StartTimer

    MyFunction = "=MyFunction("
    CountTotalCells = 0
    CountTotalFunctions = 0

    Set MySheet = Sheets("Forum Question")
    Set MyRange = MySheet.UsedRange

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        MyCellFormula = MyCell.Formula

        CountTotalCells = CountTotalCells + 1
        If InStr(1, MyCellFormula, MyFunction) > 0 Then
            CountTotalFunctions = CountTotalFunctions + 1
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    swEndTime = sw.EndTimer

    MsgBox CountTotalCells & ", " & CountTotalFunctions & ", " & swEndTime & " ms"
End Sub
```

**Method 2**

```
Private Sub TestMethod2()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim MySheet As Worksheet, MyRange As Range, MyCell As Range
    Dim MyCellAddress As String, MyCellFormula As String, MyFunction As String, MyCellFirst As String
    Dim CountTotalCells As Long, CountTotalFunctions As Long

    Dim sw, swEndTime As Long
    Set sw = New StopWatch
    sw.StartTimer

    MyFunction = "=MyFunction("
    CountTotalCells = 0
    CountTotalFunctions = 0

    Set MySheet = Sheets("Forum Question")
    Set MyRange = MySheet.UsedRange

    Set MyCell = MyRange.Cells.Find( _
        What:=MyFunction, _
        After:=[A1], _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=True _
    )

    If Not MyCell Is Nothing Then
        MyCellFirst = MyCell.Address
        Do
            Set MyCell = MyRange.FindNext(After:=MyCell)
            MyCellAddress = MyCell.Address
            MyCellFormula = "z" & MyCell.Formula

            CountTotalCells = CountTotalCells + 1
            If InStr(1, MyCellFormula, MyFunction) > 0 Then
                CountTotalFunctions = CountTotalFunctions + 1
            End If

            If MyCell Is Nothing Or MyCellAddress = MyCellFirst Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If

    Set MyCell = Nothing

    swEndTime = sw.EndTimer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    MsgBox CountTotalCells & ", " & CountTotalFunctions & ", " & swEndTime & " ms"
End Sub
```

Comment: wouldn't this post be more suited in [StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down the code.  Both modules are looping through every cell and testing to see what formula is in the cell.  You only ***see*** that in your method 1, but Excel is also check every cell in the target `Range` when it evaluates the call to `.Find`.

Let's count the function calls that touch the Worksheet in each loop. Method 1 has exactly 1:

```
MyCell.Formula
```

Method 2 has the following:

```
MyRange.FindNext
MyCell.Address
MyCell.Formula
```

...plus these comparisons...

```
MyCell Is Nothing
MyCellAddress = MyCellFirst
```

...plus this string concatenation:

```
MyCellFormula = "z" & MyCell.Formula
```

So let's add up the damage.  I took the liberty of adding profiling code to test the total time spent on each of those lines (with a much larger sample or cells):

```
Set MyCell = MyRange.Cells.Find: 0 seconds
MyCellFirst = MyCell.Address: 0.421875 seconds
Set MyCell = MyRange.FindNext(After:=MyCell): 4.3125 seconds
MyCellFormula = "z" & MyCell.Formula: 0.34375 seconds
If MyCell Is Nothing Or MyCellAddress = MyCellFirst Then Exit Do: 0.015625 seconds
```

So, the big performace hog is `.FindNext`, which isn't surprising.  It's doing a ton of work internally that is flat out skipped in Method 1 (just evaluating the 7 parameters alone...), which does simple retrievals and value string comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, I'm not trying to get usage counts. I used them in my example for testing purposes only.  What I'm trying to do is search through the workbook for every instance of the function, then for that exact cell where the function resides I will be doing other stuff.

Comment: Think of it this way... A very simple version would, for every cell my function is in, turn it yellow. Not what I'm doing, but a good example of type of logic this should accomplish.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the insight. Makes a lot of sense. I'll research a bit more and write back. Thank you!